# NodeJs Mongoose findById returns empty doc with status true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to implement CRUD operations using MEAN stack. I'm facing a problem on getting user by Id. It's showing the status true but it returns an empty document.

This is my model:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Full name can\'t be empty '
    },
    userName: {
        type: String,
        required: 'user name can\'t be empty ',
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: 'email can\'t be empty ',
        unique: true
    });

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

in my controller:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
const User = mongoose.model('User');

module.exports.getuser = (req, res, next) => {
    if(!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
        return res.status(400).send(`No record with given id : ${req.params.id}`);

    User.findById(req.params.id, (err, user) => {
        if(!err){ res.status(200).json({status: true, user}); }
        else{ console.log('Error in retriving User :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });    
}
```

This is the route:

```
router.get('/:id', jwtHelper.verifyJwtToken, ctrlUser.getuser);
```

while checking in the postman I'm getting status: true but it returns a blank document.
I'm not getting what's going on anyone please help. 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong param

replace `req.params._id` by `req.params.id` as below:

```
User.findById( req.params.id, (err, user) => {
        if(!err){ res.status(200).json({status: true, user}); }
        else{ console.log('Error in retriving User :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
```

Comment: I tried some other answer so that I used "_id" it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Another possible scenario is that _id in req.params String format instead of ObjectId.

```
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    if(!err) { 
        res.status(200).json({status: true, user}); 
    }else {
        console.log('Error in retriving User :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

the syntax for findById is not valid

the correct syntax for using findByID is

```
Adventure.findById(id, function (err, adventure) {});
```

u can also replace findById with findOne by this

```
User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, (err, user) => {
        if(!err){ res.status(200).json({status: true, user}); }
        else{ console.log('Error in retriving User :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
```

or you can use this also

```
  User.findById(req.params.id, (err, user) => {
            if(!err){ res.status(200).json({status: true, user}); }
            else{ console.log('Error in retriving User :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
        });
```

Hope this will work for you @sun

Comment: I tried using both the scenarios but it's not returning any doc @Vivek Ghanchi

Comment: I think you have empty data for lookup please check

Comment: I have inserted a few records. remaining curd operation working fine like deleting and inserting retrieving all users but on getting user by "id" is not working properly.